# NullPointerException @ Googlemap lambda expression ? (gMapsfx)

Tags: java, google-maps, javafx, lambda, nullpointerexception

Good evening,

At last, I decided to join the StackOverflow community. First of all, I want to say: My appreciation to everyone who've made this community possible (to the attendees & creators). This site has provided a lot of help to my coding problems down the road.

..this one is an exception. I've been googling for two days for help to this problem, but I just have not been able to resolve it. Any help or hints would be appreciated.

**My goal: to add GmapsFX to JavaFX application.**

First I tried to add the GmapsFX to JavaFX FXML Application but received a lot of compilation errors, which I could not resolve. Next, I decided to take the easier route and just try to implement it to plain JavaFX Application. But to my surprise, I noticed that I received the same compilation errors in the JavaFX Application as well.

I am using:

- Netbeans
- Platform 8.2
- JDK 1.8
- slf4j-API-1.7.25
- GMapsFX-2.12.0

The main class:

```
package fxmaps_2;

import com.lynden.gmapsfx.GoogleMapView;
import com.lynden.gmapsfx.MapComponentInitializedListener;
import com.lynden.gmapsfx.javascript.object.GoogleMap;
import com.lynden.gmapsfx.javascript.object.LatLong;
import com.lynden.gmapsfx.javascript.object.MapOptions;
import com.lynden.gmapsfx.javascript.object.MapTypeIdEnum;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author Tommi
 */
public class FXMaps_2 extends Application implements MapComponentInitializedListener {

    GoogleMapView mapView;
    GoogleMap map;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        mapView = new GoogleMapView();
        mapView.addMapInitializedListener(this);

        Scene scene = new Scene(mapView, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("JavaFX gMap");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(fxmaps_2.FXMaps_2.class, new String[0]);
    }

    @Override
    public void mapInitialized() {
        MapOptions mapOptions = new MapOptions();
        mapOptions.center(new LatLong(47.6097, -122.3331))
                .mapType(MapTypeIdEnum.ROADMAP)
                .overviewMapControl(false)
                .panControl(false)
                .rotateControl(false)
                .scaleControl(false)
                .streetViewControl(false)
                .zoomControl(false)
                .zoom(12);
        map = mapView.createMap(mapOptions);
    }

}
```

The output stack after trying to Run the project:

```
    ant -f C:\\Users\\Tommi\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\FXMaps_2 jfxsa-run
    init:
    Deleting: C:\Users\Tommi\Documents\NetBeansProjects\FXMaps_2\build\built-jar.properties
    deps-jar:
    Updating property file: C:\Users\Tommi\Documents\NetBeansProjects\FXMaps_2\build\built-jar.properties
    compile:
    Deleting directory C:\Users\Tommi\Documents\NetBeansProjects\FXMaps_2\dist\lib
    Copying 2 files to C:\Users\Tommi\Documents\NetBeansProjects\FXMaps_2\dist\lib
    Detected JavaFX Ant API version 1.3
    jfx-deployment:
    jar:
    Copying 14 files to C:\Users\Tommi\Documents\NetBeansProjects\FXMaps_2\dist\run1501132311
    jfx-project-run:
    Executing C:\Users\Tommi\Documents\NetBeansProjects\FXMaps_2\dist\run1501132311\FXMaps_2.jar using platform C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\jre/bin/java
    Exception in Application start method
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$154(LauncherImpl.java:182)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.lynden.gmapsfx.GoogleMapView.lambda$new$4(GoogleMapView.java:221)
        at com.lynden.gmapsfx.GoogleMapView.<init>(GoogleMapView.java:228)
        at com.lynden.gmapsfx.GoogleMapView.<init>(GoogleMapView.java:159)
        at com.lynden.gmapsfx.GoogleMapView.<init>(GoogleMapView.java:137)
        at com.lynden.gmapsfx.GoogleMapView.<init>(GoogleMapView.java:80)
        at com.lynden.gmapsfx.GoogleMapView.<init>(GoogleMapView.java:76)
        at fxmaps_2.FXMaps_2.start(FXMaps_2.java:30)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$161(LauncherImpl.java:863)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$174(PlatformImpl.java:326)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$172(PlatformImpl.java:295)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$173(PlatformImpl.java:294)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
        ... 1 more

    Exception running application fxmaps_2.FXMaps_2
    Java Result: 1
    Deleting directory C:\Users\Tommi\Documents\NetBeansProjects\FXMaps_2\dist\run1501132311
    jfxsa-run:
    BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

If I've understood correctly: the problem generates from somewhere from the GoogleMapView lambda expression? Something there is causing the nullpointerexception, which again is causing the whole "Run" to cancel?

Any hints / tips would be appriciated.

Thanks.

*edit: added gfmapsx version number

Comment: What version of _GMapsFX_ are you using?

Comment: Thank you for your reply Slaw. I am using: GMapsFX-2.12.0. (should be the latest)

Comment: Well, I just ran your code and I got no exceptions and everything seemed to display correctly. I used the Gradle build tool to run the code, however, and used Atom as an editor (shouldn't matter). Based on your output Netbeans seems to be using Ant to build and run your code. I have absolutely no experience with Ant but maybe the problem is there?

Comment: Good to hear that it is not the code that seems to be causing the problem. I've been rewriting it for quite a while now. I suppose I've better to try the Gradle build tool.. or well, try to learn about build tools overall. Just learned about those few days ago (while searching for the solution via google). Something new to learn. Thanks for help Slaw.

Comment: I can not say, that this information was not useful. Gained further valuable information indeed: there's a lot of other stuff to consider than just the programming part. Been looking through the maven build tool through the day and it seems like an excellent way to build a project. Broadening my view each day. Thank you for being part of it. All of this will be valuable information in the future (and this I can say for sure). Wishing you a great weekend!